# Java Keystore type Windows-MY/ROOT-LOCALMACHINE requires administrator permissions

Tags: java, permissions, keystore

Last year they finally fixed the issue with accessing certificates from the local machine (https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-6782021).
But it seems that accessing these certificates requires local administrator permissions - even if the user has the permission for certain certificates. How does this make sense?
So I can automatically deploy certificates to certain machines via a certificate template and grant "Local service" users permissions to the private key, but I'm not able to get these certificates! I would understand that I cann't change/store certificates, but why cann't I read them?
If i run the application as administrator or the used service user is a local administrator everything works fine. But I don't want to use such users due security reasons.

I don't want to use this hack anymore ;)
[Access Windows Local Machine Personal Keystore with Java (SunMSCAPI)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51205158/access-windows-local-machine-personal-keystore-with-java-sunmscapi/51855449)

final KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY-LOCALMACHINE", "SunMSCAPI");
keyStore.load(null, null);

java.io.IOException: java.security.KeyStoreException: Access is denied
at jdk.crypto.mscapi/sun.security.mscapi.CKeyStore.engineLoad(CKeyStore.java:737)
at jdk.crypto.mscapi/sun.security.mscapi.CKeyStore$MYLocalMachine.engineLoad(CKeyStore.java:72)
at java.base/java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1473)
at KeyStoreUtil.main(KeyStoreUtil.java:65)
Caused by: java.security.KeyStoreException: Access is denied
at jdk.crypto.mscapi/sun.security.mscapi.CKeyStore.loadKeysOrCertificateChains(Native Method)
at jdk.crypto.mscapi/sun.security.mscapi.CKeyStore.engineLoad(CKeyStore.java:734)
... 3 more

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the same issue with accessing a code signing certificate deployed to the Windows-MY-LOCALMACHINE key store using the OpenJDK `jarsigner` utility.   I have concluded that the SunMSCAPI provider enhancement created to resolve [JDK-6782021](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-6782021) is incomplete, since it fails to work for a user who has read access to the private key but is not in the local Administrators group.

> *A post from 2019 explains how Microsoft's singtool can access a Local Machine code signing certificate from a non-elevated prompt.   But it
> did not discuss the similar issue with the OpenJDK's SunMSCAPI key
> store access provider:*
>
> [Why does signtool.exe only find certificate when run as admin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56563732)
>
> *Note also that the user in that case was granted Full Control access to the private key, whereas only Read is access is needed if the use
> is strictly for signing code.*

To demonstrate the unfinished work in the JDK-6782021 enhancement, first create a self signed code signing certificate in the Local Computer's Personal certificate store from an elevated PowerShell:

```
$cert = New-SelfSignedCertificate -DNSName "JDK-6782021 Read Only Test" -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\My -Type CodeSigningCert -FriendlyName "JDK-6782021"
```

> Here is Microsoft's reference on how this works:
>
> [Powershell New-SelfSignedCert cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pki/new-selfsignedcertificate?view=windowsserver2022-ps)

From a non-elevated command prompt, if you attempt to sign an EXE file with your new certificate using signtool.exe, it will fail.  This is because the user does not yet have read access to the private key.  Likewise, an attempt to sign a JAR file using jarsigner.exe will fail for the same underlying reason.  For example:

```
C:\temp\JDK-6782021_test> signtool sign /sm /sm /i "JDK-6782021 Read Only Test" MyApp.exe
SignTool Error: No certificates were found that met all the given criteria.

C:\temp\JDK-6782021_test> jarsigner -keystore NONE -storetype Windows-MY-LocalMachine -providerClass sun.security.mscapi.SunMSCAPI MyPkg.jar JDK-6782021
jarsigner error: java.lang.RuntimeException: keystore load: java.security.KeyStoreException: error 5, Access is denied.
```

Running the same commands from an elevated prompt results in success because, as we'll see below, the Administrators group was granted Full Control access when the certificate was created:

```
C:\temp\JDK-6782021_test> signtool sign /sm /i "JDK-6782021 Read Only Test"  MyApp.exe
Done Adding Additional Store
Successfully signed: MyApp.exe

C:\temp\JDK-6782021_test> jarsigner -keystore NONE -storetype Windows-MY-LOCALMACHINE -providerClass sun.security.mscapi.SunMSCAPI MyPkg.jar JDK-6782021
jar signed.
```

To grant access from the non-elevated prompt, launch the MMC, add the Certificates snap-in, select the Computer account, select the Local Computer, click Finish, and click Okay. Expand Certificates(Local Computer), expand Personal, and click Certificates.   Select the certificate issues to/by "JDK-6782021 Read Only Test".   From the right click menu, select "All Tasks / Manage Private Keys ...".   A Permissions dialog will pop up.  From there, Add your user to the list, and Allow only Read access.  Here is how it should should look:

[image]

Once again test the code signing commands from the non-elevated command prompt:

```
C:\temp\JDK-6782021_test> signtool sign /sm /i "JDK-6782021 Read Only Test"  MyApp.exe
Done Adding Additional Store
Successfully signed: MyApp.exe

C:\temp\JDK-6782021_test> jarsigner -keystore NONE -storetype Windows-MY-LOCALMACHINE -providerClass sun.security.mscapi.SunMSCAPI MyPkg.jar JDK-6782021
jarsigner error: java.lang.RuntimeException: keystore load: java.security.KeyStoreException: error 5, Access is denied.
```

The failure of the jarsigner in this circumstance was not expected.  Since `signtool` succeeded, `jarsigner` should also have succeeded.  If elevation is required for the SunMSCAPI key store access provider to access a Local Machine certificate, then `jarsigner` should have self-elevated.

The test case covering a non-administrative user, including read-only access to the private key of the certificate being accessed, may have been omitted in the testing of JDK-6782021.  It might also have been inadvertently tested from an elevated prompt.  Whatever the cause, the net result is that this functionality will fail for users forbidden from being members of a local Administrators group.

**Update**:  A simple Java application can be used to trigger the exception reported by the OP.  For example:

> To prove the issue is with the SunMSCAPI provider, and not with
> jarsigner, run the following Java code in place of jarsigner in the
> test above:
>
> ```
>     try {
>         Security.addProvider(new SunMSCAPI());
>         KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY-LOCALMACHINE");
>       keyStore.load(null, null);
>         Enumeration<String> aliases = keyStore.aliases();
>         for (int i = 0 ; aliases.hasMoreElements() ; i++) {
>           System.out.println( aliases.nextElement() );
>         }
>     } catch (Exception e) {
>         throw new RuntimeException(e);
>     }
> ```
>
> When executed without elevation, executing this code will also output
> the same stack trace reported above.  Otherwise, when executed with
> elevation, it will list the friendly names (aliases) of all
> certificates in the Windows Local Computer's personal certificates
> keystore, including "JDK-6782021".

**Update 2**:  This issue was opened as bug report for OpenJDK 17 and 20 on July 26, 2023:

> [**JDK-8313367** SunMSCAPI cannot read Local Computer certs w/o
> Windows elevation](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8313367)

Tools used:

- signtool.exe version 10.0.17763.0
- jarsigner.exe and java.exe from OpenJDK 17.0.8 or 20.0.2

Operating systems used:

- Windows Server 2019
- Windows 11 version 22H2

Comment: @Andreas-Gusenbauer a candidate fix for JDK-8313367 is pending review:  https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/pull/16687

Answer (score 0):

If it helps to have code that works independent of whether any of the JDK bugs (mentioned elsewhere on this page) are fixed, consider this alternative: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77552537/2452569